# Cannot edit files in WordPress theme editor

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

Today, I encounter a strange problem.

At first, I try to update header.php in Theme Editor, then click "Update" button, then I see "Update successfully" confirmation. However, after some time, when I check header.php again, I find its contents are not updated at all.

I try several times but all fails. So I log out, and then try to login and then try to update the file again, this time I get the error "nonce_failure".

I think the issue may be caused by some plugins, so I try to disable the latest plugin I have installed, i.e., Asset Cleanup Pro. However, this time I get another error "The link you followed has expired. Please try again".

So, what is the problem?

**Update**

I try the following steps:

1. Add *example.com/blogs/wp-admin* rule in cloudflare which set Cache level to ByPass.
2. Add *example.com/blogs/wp-login.php* rule in cloudlfare which set Cache level to ByPass.
3. Clear the cached file in browser(Do not clear the cookies).

Then the issue is solved.

Thank you very much.

Comment: A "nonce failure" indicates an issue with session or form handling. Try cleaning your caches or use a fresh anonymous browser window.

Comment: @arkascha, thank you very much. I follow your instructions and set some Cloudflare rules, and my issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks for the Update and for informing all that "the issue is solved."